# Keeping json data in the order it was inserted - django

Tags: django, json

I have a [`JSONField`](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield) in my django app. The data might look like this :

```
{
"05/2013" : 101,
"04/2013" : 100.9,
"03/2013" : 100.5,
"02/2013" : 100.3,
"01/2013" : 100.3
}
```

It's a price index. When I fetch the data from the field I want to preserve the order in which the data was inserted.

I looked at the [advanced option](https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield#advanced-usage) that uses `OrderedDict`. The Dict (I guess) uses lexical sort so the output losses it's original order in this format.
I've tried flipping the dates to the format `2012-01`,`2012-02` and so on but the output is still scrambled. Partial output :

```
"2011-08":104.2,
  "2011-09":104,
  "2011-02":102.3,
  "2011-03":102.5,
  "2011-01":102,
  "2011-06":104,
  "2011-07":103.7,
  "2011-04":103.1,
  "2011-05":103.6,
  "2013-04":100.9,
  "2013-05":101,
  "2012-10":106,
  "2012-11":105.5,
```

I'm not sure what kind of sort is this and i'm one step behind on finding a solution.
Appreciate any thoughts.

**EDIT:**
This is the model field declaration

```
from jsonfield import JSONField
...
values = JSONField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("values"),load_kwargs={'object_pairs_hook': collections.OrderedDict})
...
```

Comment: If you want to preserve the insertion order, you might want to populate your field by sorting the old value first. Something like `price = OrderedDict(sorted(price.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))`

Comment: @Germano - can you explain your answer - I'm not sure where this line is going ... pre_save ?

Comment: I don't know if you have a legacy database or you're starting from scratch, nor if you are going to insert more the one item at a time. That information will let you choose the right place to insert that code.

Comment: Dictionaries are by definition unordered. Not lexical or anything, even though the order will be consistent within a single session there is no expected ordering. Having that said, I would assume that the advanced example should work but from your response I assume it does not. You could easily solve this by using a `sorted(the_dict.items())` but that doesn't explain why it's not working. As long as you have the dates in the format `yyyy-mm` a lexical sort should work.

Comment: i'm strating from scratch so i'm flexible. mostly i'll be inserting data in bulks but I might update. In this example - I'm abviously going to add a row every month. @Wolph - I'm new to this but from what i understood in the documentation on github this should preserve the order it was inserted in and not sort by the items (how can you do that any way ? .... json might get pretty complex).

Comment: @haki Since the insertion order should be consistent with the key sorting, can't you just sort your field value once retrieved from the database? You can make a simple `property` in your model.

Comment: Im inserting and keeping the data in json format. Im not constructing it from tje db. I think my solution might be to just sort it every time im fetching.

Comment: did you get any soln?, i am having this same issue on django 3.2.4, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69317306/django-defining-a-json-type-on-model-makes-jsonb-instead-of-json

Answer (score 13):

If you need to maintain key order in a JSONFIeld you can override the db_type for the native JSONField to use json rather than jsonb:

```
class RawJSONField(JSONField):

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'json'
```

From the [Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/datatype-json.html):

*The major practical difference is one of efficiency. The json data type stores an exact copy of the input text, which processing functions must reparse on each execution; while jsonb data is stored in a decomposed binary format that makes it slightly slower to input due to added conversion overhead, but significantly faster to process, since no reparsing is needed. jsonb also supports indexing, which can be a significant advantage.*

If you don't need to index your data based on the contents of the JSON blob and really do need to maintain the key order that was created when you instantianted your dictionary (perhaps you are using a client side library that makes assumption on JSON key order), then this might work for you.

Comment: Warning: this workaround does not work upgrading Django3.0.6 to Django3.1.2 where django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField is replaced with django.models.JSONField. Future readers might see if this is resolved via this bug report: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32135#ticket

Comment: Thanks for the heads up @Michael. From the ticket it looks like this isn't going to be supported going forward which is pretty disappointing.

Comment: @RedBlueThing hello sir, do you have any fix for django 3.2.4, I am dealing with this json and jsonb issue right now, please have a look on my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69317306/django-defining-a-json-type-on-model-makes-jsonb-instead-of-json

Comment: Dont forget to run makemigrations ;)

Comment: Warning: this could have side effects. For instance, some EPs of mine stop working because i was doing aggregations with related models:
ProgrammingError: could not identify an equality operator for type json

Answer (score 2):

this is interesting question, especially because there is no guarantee about order of fields in the javascript object, JSON itself or python dict

taking above into consideration, if we will get our order set properly in some combination of database + serialization + deserialization + presentation it will work only for this (quite narrow) configuration

e.g. django-jsonfield serializes (by default) JSON to the text field, so on the database level it may be safe, but deserialization from few json modules (json, simplejson, ujson, yajl) is done to dictionary and then all order is lost

django 1.9 introduces native postgresql JSONField - and here you do not have guarantee even on the database level, because data is stored internally as jsonb - binary optimized JSON

in my opinion, instead of searching for serialization to `OrderedDict`, better to change how data is stored, if order is important - let's store data in the table:

```
[{date: "05/2013", price: 101},
 {date: "04/2013", price: 100.9},
 {date: "03/2013", price: 100.5},
 {date: "02/2013", price: 100.3},
 {date: "01/2013", price: 100.3}]
```

We have guarantee of the order, data can be processed in linear matter and we are not depending on special implementations.

Comment: Python 3.6+ does guarantee to preserve order of keys. It was released after your answer though.