# Django defining a json type on model makes jsonb instead of json

Tags: json, django, postgresql, jsonb

I am using the [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) for my Django model for JSON type but in the background, it makes my attributes column type `JSONB` which I don't want to do here because it breaks my exact order of JSON'S internal field that I pushed from my frontend app. You can see the order of fields is not my exact value. To store it as it is, I need to use JSON instead of jsonb. So my question is how to do that?

**What I pushed:**

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "title": "action_right",
  "additionalProperties": true,
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "label",
      "url"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "label": {
        "type": "string",
        "custom_type": "string",
        "title": "label",
        "default": ""
      },
      "url": {
        "type": "string",
        "custom_type": "string",
        "title": "url",
        "default": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**What is stored:**

```
{
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "label",
      "url"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "url": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "url",
        "default": "",
        "custom_type": "string"
      },
      "label": {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "label",
        "default": "",
        "custom_type": "string"
      }
    }
  },
  "title": "action_right",
  "additionalProperties": true
}
```

**Code snippets:**

```
class Component(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    attributes = models.JSONField(default=dict, help_text='Component attributes in JSONSchema')
```

**Notes:**

> PostgreSQL has two native JSON based data types: json and jsonb. The
> main difference between them is how they are stored and how they can
> be queried. PostgreSQL’s json field is stored as the original string
> representation of the JSON and must be decoded on the fly when queried
> based on keys. The jsonb field is stored based on the actual structure
> of the JSON which allows indexing. The trade-off is a small additional
> cost on writing to the jsonb field. JSONField uses jsonb.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (may need to be tweaked):

```
import json

class RawJSONField(models.JSONField):
    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'text'

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return json.dumps(value)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return json.loads(value)
```

in some model:

```
class Calculation(models.Model):
    calc_result = RawJSONField(_("Calc result data"), default = dict)
```

other variant:

```
from django.db import models
import json

class RawJSONField(models.TextField):
    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return json.dumps(value)

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return json.loads(value)
```